# Nested sp_executesql not working with output variable

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sp-executesql, parameter-sniffing

I am trying to call a stored procedure (with output variable) using `sp_executesql` but within another stored procedure. I wrote the following, but still not able to get trhough what that error means

This would be called from webservice code:

```
exec sp1 'obj1',@params
```

Here `obj` and `params` are of `nvarchar(max)`

Definition of `sp1` is :

```
Alter procedure [dbo].[sp1 ]  
    @procname nvarchar(max),  
    @params nvarchar(max)  
as   
    declare @temp varchar(15)  

    if @procname = 'obj1'  
    begin  
        set @params = @params +  ',@Newval  varchar(15) output'  
        EXEC sp_executesql @sp2,@params,@Newval=@temp OUTPUT  
    end
```

Definition of `sp2`:

Here I am returning @Newval

Error I am getting :

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near ','.

Also in 2 in place of `exec` statement , I have tried following:

```
 EXEC sp_executesql @sp2, @params, @temp OUTPUT;
```

Results in the same error.

```
set @sql='sp2,' + ' @params ' + ',@params,@temp OUTPUT'
EXEC sp_executesql (@sql)
```

Also results in the same error.

I need this dynamic selection of stored procedures in sp1 and params is a `nvarchar(max)` string of parameters and their values, some of them are varchar and are embedded in ''value'' format but this string is fine as I am able to call the underlying sp2 with this.

Additional info, it it helps.

```
EXEC sp_executesql @sp2,@params,@Newval=@temp OUTPUT
```

in this @params is combination of keys and vlaue pairs for the final sp. something like :
'@key1="a",@key2="b"'
and so on, I can not predefined the @params but it is dynamic and it is working 
fine when I run it with

```
exec (@sql)
```

Format while whole of the name, params are embedded in the @sql

Answer (score 0):

If `@params=''` or `NULL` then your `,` before `@Newval` is irrelevant. I suggest you to check:

```
IF NULLIF(@params,'') IS NULL or @params IS NULL
SET @params = '@Newval  varchar(15) output'
ELSE 
SET @params = @params + ',@Newval  varchar(15) output'
```

You are passing `@sp2` maybe you need this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp1]  
    @procname nvarchar(max),  
    @params nvarchar(max)  
AS   
    DECLARE @temp varchar(15)

    IF @procname = 'obj1'  
    BEGIN  
        SET @params = @params +  ',@Newval  varchar(15) output'  
        EXEC sp_executesql N'EXEC sp2 @someparam1, @someparam2, @Newval varchar(15) OUTPUT', @params, @someparam1 = 1, @someparam2 = 2, @Newval=@temp OUTPUT  
    END
```

**EDIT**

Working example:

```
USE [AdventureWorks]
GO

DECLARE @procname nvarchar(max) = 'EXEC [dbo].[uspGetWhereUsedProductID] @StartProductID, @CheckDate',  
        @params nvarchar(max) = '@StartProductID int, @CheckDate date'

EXEC sp_executesql @procname, @params, @StartProductID = 1, @CheckDate = '2015-10-17'
GO
```

Comment: Thanks but @Params is neither null nor ' ' :(

Comment: If I remove the output variable requirement I can still call sp2 with following  declare @sql nvarchar(max); set @sql='sp2' + ' ' + @params;  exec (@sql) but that is just defeating the purpose of getting output variable and also sp_executesql is not being used in this case. Please consider I am using sql server 2005 if that helps

Comment: What you send in '@params' from php?

Comment: I am not sending from php but a webservice call from java, string is '@a=1,@b=''PL_30338'',@c=1,@d=''P10563'',@e=''K_3749'' , this very same string works in my comment section mentioned way and also if just pass it along with sp1 name with exec 'sp2' + ' ' + @params

Comment: I understand. I add some info to my answer. Please, try.

Comment: Thanks @gofr1 , I tried that just now and found out I tried earlier too. Error is  Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '='.

Comment: does it seem some problem with output variable assignment ?  @gofr1

Comment: I add change second query in my answer please check it, and add working example with `[AdventureWorks]` DB.

Comment: Yes it is a problem with getting parameters to SP.

Comment: Thanks @gofr1 for helping me but I tried this solution, in the edit part, it is still showing the same error with '=', Actually I can not pass any additional parameter along with sp name and only possibility is in a combined string params which contains both parameters and their values for the final sp. I tried performing your suggestion which is adding the keyword exec along with sp name and got the same error. :(   Also I found you added the newval varchar(15) output twice while putting in text, This way I have this in first param which is the name of the sp and also again in params,

Comment: Working example from edit actually works (I checked) your sp got OUTPUT parameter? Yes, newval must be declared as output from sp then determine where to put it (another variable)

Comment: Thanks @gofr1 , I agree with the point that it should ideally works as it does in the standard case, i.e. working example but in my case it is even simpler and does not work. I actually put the newval varchar(15) output along with sp name block and again added it to params still the same result. :(